# Prove conditional independence for autoregressive process

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, independence

Consider $x_t = \phi x_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$, $\epsilon_t \stackrel{iid}{\sim} N(0,1)$,$|\phi| \lt 1$,$x_1 \sim N(0, \frac{1}{1-\phi^2})$,then we have $x_t | x_1, ..., x_{t-1} \sim N(\phi x_{t-1},1)$ for $t = 2,...,n$. How can I prove $x_s$ and $x_t$ with $1 \le s \lt t \le n$ are conditionally independent given $\{x_{s+1},...,x_{t-1}\}$ if $t-s > 1$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would work out $\mathbb{P}[x_s \in A, x_t \in B]$ for general sets $A, B \subset \mathbb{R}$. Given $t-s>1$, the joint distribution of $x_s$ and $x_t$ is just the product of the distributions, because $x_t \sim N(\phi x_{t-1},1)$, and $x_{t-1}$ is known. Thus we get independence via the integration.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst I can't get it. Could you provide detailed solution?